# www-data user can't write to /tmp folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

**Linux 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Permissions seem wide open

```
>>> ll /
...
drwxrwxrwt   8 root   root         4096 May  1 02:44 tmp/
```

Denied access:

```
sudo -u www-data echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt
-bash: /tmp/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Disk space seems OK:

```
>>> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            980M     0  980M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  8.2M  192M   5% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  6.3G  1.1G  86% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Check your selinux logs.

Comment: @EEAA Is selinux used in Ubuntu 16?

Comment: Just use /dev/shm instead of tmp. Your apps will run even faster that way...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/4358

Comment: Is there a `/tmp/test.txt` file already? What is the output of `ls -alh /tmp/test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file already exists.
In this case, if it has been created by another process already, the system will not allow you to either modify or delete it since you're not the owner.
In this case, right after the file is created, you might want to

```
chmod 666 /tmp/test.txt
```

I had the same exact problem, and this was the solution.

Comment: In my case, the file does not yet exist https://serverfault.com/q/1074904/249412